# Почему не удаётся сделать галерею с эффектом(слайдер)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Галерею вызываю в нужном месте через айди страницы (создал страницу и там создал галерею).

```
<?php
    $id = 187;
    $p = get_page($id);
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $p->post_content);
?>
```

Указал ссылку на "медиафайл". Сейчас картинки открываются в новом окне. Пробовал ставить плагины вроде Lightbox , Fancybox для того , чтоб картинка открывался в полном размере и появлялся слайдер.
Безрезультатно. Мне как то раньше удавалось это сделать, не могу вспомнить как.

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать плагин https://github.com/Axeleus/yd-gallery писал его для проекта musichq.ru будет выглядеть как здесь http://musichq.ru/guano-apes-anabuk-2016.html